# Did not find reference matching RestoreAssemblyResources AssemblyName metadata 'Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging'

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, push

I want to use Push Notifications in my Xamarin application. 
I used the following namespaces

```
using Microsoft.AppCenter;
using Microsoft.AppCenter.Push;
```

but I got the following error

> Did not find reference matching RestoreAssemblyResources AssemblyName
>   metadata 'Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging' FirePush.Android.

If I add the nuget package `Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging` the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, make sure you have all the packages that are required from firebase are included, and the packages are added to the respective native projects. 
make sure to have the latest updates versions of the packages,
then, refer this blog and do the simple steps mentioned over there,

> http://evanp.net/xamarin-did-not-find-reference-matching-restoreassemblyresources-assemblyname-metadata/

once you are done with that clean the solution and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is that `AppCenter` push notifications are wrapped over FCM which means it is directly dependent on it.

Required packages:

Since you are using the app centre in your application you will need `Microsoft.AppCenter.Push.`(Windows) or `App Center Push.` (MAC) package from NuGet,

Other than that you will have to add `Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging` Nuget to add the dependent firebase API's

Once you are done with this you will have to clean build and maybe even clear bin obj for it to work.

Comment: The problem is that even if you just pick up and add a package Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging to an default project without specifying a namespace, an error already occurs. I cleared bin and obj(